# NgRx Update entity by name is possible instead of id?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-entity

```
export interface **UpdateStr**<T> {
    **id**: string; // need to update by name
    changes: Partial<T>;
}
```

I need to update by name, instead of id

Answer (score 0):

Entity is built around having an `id`.
Either update manually, or use `adapter.map`.

```
return adapter.map(
      (entity) =>
        entity.name === action.name
          ? updatedEntity // update entity with based on name
          : entity // return the entity
      state
    );
```